# How do i create a video from a static image and an audio file?

Tags: python, image, mp3, mp4

Im trying to write a program that creates an mp4 from a static image and an audio file.

Here is the code im using so far:

```
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip, ImageClip

def mp3PNGMerge(fileSaveName):
    
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip("[PATH TO AUDIO]")
    image_clip = ImageClip("PATH TO IMAGE")
    video_clip = image_clip.set_audio(audio_clip)
    video_clip.duration = audio_clip.duration
    video_clip.fps = 1
    video_clip.write_videofile(fileSaveName + '_CLIP.mp4')

mp3PNGMerge('[OUTPUT FILE NAME]')
```

However when this is run, the program creates a video the length of the audio clip but does not play the audio, it is completely silent.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be to set your sound on **videoClip** not **imageClip**.

I don't use MoviePY or Python but from looking at the docs, I would try as:

```
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip, ImageClip

def mp3PNGMerge(fileSaveName):
    
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip("[PATH TO AUDIO]")
    image_clip = ImageClip("PATH TO IMAGE")
    
    video_clip = VideoClip(image_clip)
    video_clip.set_audio(audio_clip)
    video_clip.duration = audio_clip.duration
    
    video_clip.fps = 30
    video_clip.write_videofile(fileSaveName + '_CLIP.mp4')

mp3PNGMerge('[OUTPUT FILE NAME]')
```

I don't know if it will get you on the right track (*eg:* maybe `video_clip.set_audio( ... )` is supposed to be set as `video_clip.audio( ... )`. The code logic should be correct.

Let me know how it goes (*eg:* I can delete this post if it's not a correct Answer).

Comment: 'ImageClip' object is not callable

Comment: @nCoder What version of MoviePy, and are you getting any error message? It's possible there has been a code update. See if [this example setup](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/bc8d1a831d2d1f61abfdf1779e8df95d523947a5/tests/test_VideoClip.py#L331) works for you.  A test could be like: `vid_clip = video(start_time=0.2, end_time=0.6)` then follows `img_clip = vid_clip .to_ImageClip(t=0.1, duration=3.0)`

Answer (score 0):

change the video_clip.fps to 30,
audio file can't be played on 1 fps

```
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip, ImageClip

def mp3PNGMerge(fileSaveName):

audio_clip = AudioFileClip("[PATH TO AUDIO]")
image_clip = ImageClip("PATH TO IMAGE")
video_clip = image_clip.set_audio(audio_clip)
video_clip.duration = audio_clip.duration
video_clip.fps = 30
video_clip.write_videofile(fileSaveName + '_CLIP.mp4')

mp3PNGMerge('[OUTPUT FILE NAME]')
```